# what does it means these errors in obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

This is the first error:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BNRHypnosisView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in BNRHypnosisViewController.o
>        (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_BNRHypnosisViewController)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

The second is:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What does these errors mean?

Comment: what kinda code does present such compiler errors?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows NO research effort -- there are tons of results here or on Google

Comment: @holex the one he is missing presents these kinds of errors :D

Comment: @Daij-Djan, I meant: how the entire project looks. :)

Comment: @holex I know - I was being sarcastic :) 'towards' the question that is

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `@implementation` for the class?

Have you imported a .m file instead of a .h file?

Comment: @DavidDume what about implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Errors come both form the linker (the pice that combines compiled code into one file) and says that he can't find all he needs to do that. He misses the class `BNRHypnosisView` (especially for 64bit)

- do you have an m file for it?
- does it come from library? e.g. cocoaPods
- is the library 64-bit compatible?

**==> you need to add and m file or a library with the @implementation of the class.**

A Header file doesn't REALLY add it. The header file only makes it known to others that the implementation will be there.... if you want, think of headers as roadsigns with townies and implementations as towns

Comment: sorry but i don't understand :) i'm new at these things :)

Comment: sorry then - im afraid I can't help you then. don't know how else I could say it. -- maybe this isn't the right thing for SO? maybe you should look into a book/tutorial/tutor? (No pun intended)